# How to remove stain from wooden door?

Tags: wood, doors, removal, stain

I bought an intricately carved door from Turkey. The door is beautiful with light wood. However, they put an orange stain on it. I did not want stain. I wanted natural. It cannot be returned. How can I remove or lighten the stain? Best products?

Comment: Picture? Species of wood, if you know?

Comment: Check out the [woodworking.se] sister site for loads of information on refinishing wooden products. Since it's a stain, though, the only way to get it off is going to be by sanding which will, most likely, cause damage to the carving. You may have to learn to live with it. Also, asking about "best products" is explicitly off topic and might get your question closed.

Comment: Contact the seller and make sure it is a stain(what type) they put on, instead of a protective covering.  They should know the best way to remove the stain/covering if one was put on.

Answer (score 0):

Since the door is intricately carved, you'll probably want a liquid or gell stripper. Most just brush on and than are wiped/lightly scraped off.  Sanding also works but it's a very slow process unless the surface is smooth. You'd want to closely follow the directions of any product used and maybe get with the company you bought it from to find out the type of wood and type of stain they put on it.

Comment: Strippers will remove the top layer of coating, but they won't get stain out. It is after all, a _stain_. It's soaked into the grain of the wood (not all that deeply, TBH, but it has) and isn't just sitting on the surface like a paint does.

Comment: @FreeMan         I've used steel wool and strippers to remove stain after the first coat or two were removed. Maybe I was just lucky but I had a happy desk. The steel wool idea was right on the instructions of the stripper for removing stain.

Comment: Was it "intricately carved"? Heck, a belt sander or random orbit sander will take off enough wood to get rid of a stain job, but they'll also destroy the work that the OP paid for... Maybe he'll have some (enough) success with strippers to be satisfying.

Comment: As always, TEST ON AN INCONSPICUOUS AREA BEFORE DOING ANYTHING YOU MIGHT REGRET. Blotchy is probably worse than dyed. Another alternative, of course, may be to layer more color over it to try to get it back to where you wanted it, or go whole hog and apply paint or a Japanese-style dark lacquer, though you'd lose more of the wood grain.